# Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated for IP

Tags: php

I am getting this error:
Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated; If you would like to pass it by reference, modify the declaration of ip_valid().

somewhere in these lines of code. Problem is I am not that strong in PHP to figure out what I need to modify to fix it.

Any advice would be apreciated.

```
function getIP () 
{
    $check = array(
            'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR',
            'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_VIA', 'HTTP_X_COMING_FROM', 'HTTP_COMING_FROM',
            'HTTP_CLIENT_IP'
            );

    foreach ( $check as $c ) {
        if ( ip_valid ( &$_SERVER [ $c ] ) ) {
            return ip_first ( $_SERVER [ $c ] );
        }
    }

    return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

}

Thnaks in advance

Wayne

Comment: Here: `if ( ip_valid ( &$_SERVER [ $c ] ) ) {`

Comment: I see answers stating _just remove the ampersand_ which of course will pass it by value. One could assume that there is a reason why it should have been passed by reference, failing to state that the declaration of `ip_valid` can also be changed to `ip_valid(&$ip_to_check);`

Answer (score 1):

Try without the ampersand:

```
ip_valid ( $_SERVER [ $c ] )
```

As with that you're forcing [by-reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

Although, noticeably you don't do this for the call to `ip_first` when passing in the same thing, so I would wonder what made you think it was right in the first place and why you did it differently in the second instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `&` from `ip_valid ( &$_SERVER [ $c ] )`.